# jQuery queue $.post requests

Tags: jquery, post, asynchronous

I have Action, that returns data for charts on page. It takes chartType parameter and returns charts data. Page uses jQuery and `$.post` function to call for it. Here is example:

```
var fillChart = function (chartData){ /* fill routine here */};

$(function () {
    $.post(
       '/Charts/ChartsJson',
       'chartType=Type1', 
       fillChart, 
       'json'); 

    $.post(
       '/Charts/ChartsJson',
       'chartType=Type2', 
       fillChart, 
       'json');

    // other calls here [*]
});
```

I have array of chartTypes, that should be processed. If I add all calls after commented line, then they all will be sent at one time. It's ok, if there are from 1 to 3 items. But if there are more items, then it's bad for performance. 

Is there any way to restrict amount of simultaneously executed post requests?

I know, that I could use callback of first post, which would invoke second, and so on... My question is: "Is there any other way?"

**UPD:** Each call is already partitioned. (And amount of items in my array is not always known.) This action return about 1000 complex elements per call, and different `chartType` says which table to use (and what logic for extraction data)
Total extraction of all data can take 20, even 40 seconds. So I want to display it on the go, as it's been processed.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098826/how-can-i-call-ajax-synchronously-without-my-web-page-freezing

Comment: You are right. Should  I delete my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had good success setting up an ad-hoc "message queue".  The messages can be json objects with the parameters for the posts as the data.  You can have any number of workers pulling objects off the queue.

For example:

```
var ajax_message_queue = [];

ajax_message_queue.push({
  "ajaxtype" : "post",
  "action"   : '/Charts/ChartsJson',
  "data"     : handlers.fillChart,
  "datatype" : "json"
});
```

A worker would simply be a setTimeout based function that pops off the oldest message, and executes it.  The worker can then be blocked from popping the next message until the first is complete.  If you want the worker can even be made to redo the request if it fails.

Comment: I like it, thanks. Where can see example, please. (No need to clean it for me, just give me url, I'll handle)

Comment: Unfortunately all the places I have used it are behind admin sections and require a log in or are internal network only.

Answer (score 1):

This is done automatically by the browser -- a web browser will not send more than a certain number of HTTP requests to any single server at any one time.  They will be automatically queued and executed when complete.

I would suggest rewriting your serverside code to allow the submission of multiple items in one go, if you want to improve performance.

Comment: @The_Smallest I'm not sure what you mean by "each post request calls for big-part".  My suggestion is that you send all the data for the whole array in one POST request.

Comment: but also be advised that not all browsers have the same settings, some may restrict more than others.

Comment: This is true, however the maximum connections per server varies by browser (and version). Firefox's current maximum seems to be 15, while Chrome is 6. IE7 is 4 for fast connections and 2 for slow connections, while IE8 is between 2 and 6, depending on connection. AFAIK, there is no way to cap this besides programmatic queuing of your requests.

Comment: @The_Smallest Reading your edit, it is clear that you should just leave this to the browser.  You could write some programmatic queueing system, but it will be a bigger performance hindrance than boost.

Comment: My experience says when I need specific order of POST requests, browser is not enough. One request could be faster that other.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send all data at once. Re-structure your input array to have a `chartType` key. That way in backend you could proccess it accordingly