# In a node.js API how do I perform tasks that must be synchronous without freezing the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

To start off this is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to do file copies to an array of servers. There are several steps that must be completed in a specific order before and after these copies (for example, stopping IIS, backing up and clearing folders, running a bat file, etc) so they are not single operations.

To make this super easy I wrote an API in node.js that does simple tasks like copy files and folders, delete folders, etc. I then wrote a frontend in node.js using an express generator and Pug that uses javascript XMLHhttpRequests to send commands to the API depending on what I needed to do. I have the API written and running as well as the frontend. Now on to the problems:

If I have my XMLHttpRequest run in synchronous mode (example: xhttp.open("POST", url , false);) when the command is sent to the API to copy a folder if the folder takes several minutes to copy the browser freezes. Chrome displays a "Page Frozen" error. However, the job gets done correctly.

If I have my XMLHttpRequest run in asynchronous mode (example: xhttp.open("POST", url , true);) then every command gets sent to the API at once so that the fastest operation completes first and the commands are out of order. The copy will fail.

I've tried searching for a way to make it so that each operation sent from the frontend javascript has to return a SUCCESS (or 200 response) from the API before moving on to the next command but so far all I've seen is "just use synchronous". Right now that's what I'm doing. That doesn't seem like the best solution even though it works. Is there a better way to do this in a way that won't freeze the browser?

Comment: There’s nothing there that “must” be synchronous; you just have to start one request in some handler called when the other request completes. Look into promises for a convenient way to deal with that.

Comment: WebSockets or Server Side Events

Comment: You are confusing "synchronous" with "sequential". You need the latter, not the former.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with how the server is implemented (node, php, assembler...). The browser freezes if you instruct your XMLHttpRequest to block until the response is received.

Comment: >>You are confusing "synchronous" with "sequential". 
Yea that seems to be the case. So what is the best way to handle this? I'm thinking some for loop craziness for each step but that doesn't seem like it would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by writing a function to handle the requests, setting a counter (for the steps of the process), and putting a switch statement in the if statement for the result. It wasn't exactly what I needed but the basics of my solution is in the answers to this question: [How can I call ajax synchronously without my web page freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098826/how-can-i-call-ajax-synchronously-without-my-web-page-freezing)

Here's what I did in case it helps anyone else who finds this question:

```
function myFunction (step, params, url) {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         switch(step) {
            case 2:
               //url and params are set here, and step 2 is done here
               myFunction(step, params, url);
               break;
            case 3:
               // and so on and so forth
         }
       }
       xhttp.open("POST", url , true);
       xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xhttp.send(params);
       step++;
}

//kick off the function
var step = 1;
var url = "my URL to the API with call";
var parameters = "my parameters";
myFunction(step, parameters, url);
```